# create a function to sum the odd square in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
 sumoddsquare' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
 sumoddsquare' = sum [x^2 | x <- [1..5], odd x]
```

My desired output is `35`

The syntax error I get is

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a] -> a'
    with actual type `[Integer]'
    In the expression: [x ^ 2 | x <- [1 .. 9999], odd x]
    In an equation for sumoddsquare':
        sumoddsquare' = [x ^ 2 | x <- [1 .. 9999], odd x]
```

Can you explain this syntax error and also provide a solution for this question?

Comment: Rather than `odd`, you could also use Haskell's list inference, `[1,3..9999]`

Answer (score 3):

You've given `sumoddsquare'` the type `Num a => [a] -> a`, but you've left off any parameter.  Maybe you meant

```
sumoddsquare' xs = sum [x^2 | x <- xs, odd x]
```

Although the `Num` constraint is not sufficient here, inspect the types of `^2` and `odd` to determine what you should be using. (spoilers below)

---

Judging by the error message, you've actually defined `sumoddsquare'` in your code as

```
sumoddsquare' :: [a] -> a
sumoddsquare' = [x^2 | x <- [1..9999], odd x]
```

Rather than what you've posted above.  Now, you've given the type `[a] -> a` to `sumoddsquares'` explicitly, the compiler takes that as a fact, but then it sees the definition.  You don't define the argument explicitly in the definition, so the compiler thinks you're defining the function in point-free style.  When it sees the right hand side of the `=`, it gets confused because `[x^2 | x <- [1..9999], odd x]` has the type `[Integer]`, but it has already accepted the fact that `sumoddsquares'` has the type `[a] -> a`.  It doesn't know how to reconcile this, so it throws the error you see.

---

You can usually find the source of these types of error messages by commenting out the explicit type signature.  If it then compiles, you can inspect the type in GHCi by doing

```
> :load sumoddsquare_no_type_sig.hs
> :type sumoddsquare'
[Integer]
```

And this would tell you that `sumoddsquare'` is not a function.  However, you want it to be a function, so how do you fix this?  First, look at the definition.  Are all of your arguments declared explicitly?  If no, add them.

```
-- sumoddsquare' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumoddsquare' xs = [x^2 | x <- [1..9999], odd x]
```

Then you see

```
> :reload
> :type sumoddsquare'
[a] -> [Integer]
```

That's at least a function, but how do we get from the very general type `[a]` to `[Integer]`?  Since we currently know nothing about `a`, then this function must not depend on the first argument at all!  We can then look through our definition to find where a list might go

```
-- sumoddsquare' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumoddsquare' xs = [x^2 | x <- xs, odd x]
--                             ^--- This is the only place I saw a list used
```

Then

```
> :reload
> :type sumoddsquare'
Integral a => [a] -> [a]
```

That's closer!  We see that the input has been restricted to `Integral` and we return a more general type than just `[Integer]`.  This tells us we first need to fix the constraint in our type signature from `Num a` to `Integral a`.  The last puzzle is figuring out how to convert `Integral a => [a]` into `Integral a => a`.  We want to sum, so now we see that we've left out the `sum` function in front of the list comprehension

```
-- sumoddsquare' :: Integral a => [a] -> a
sumoddsquare' xs = sum [x^2 | x <- xs, odd x]
```

And finally

```
> :reload
> :type sumoddsquare'
Integral a => [a] -> a
```

We have a type that matches what we want.  We can now uncomment the type signature in our source code.

---

As a bonus, this problem can be solved entirely with higher order functions as

```
sumoddsquares' xs = sum $ map (^2) $ filter odd $ xs
-- or point free as
-- sumoddsquares' = sum . map (^2) . filter odd
```

And in fact, all list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for `map`s, `filter`s, and `concat`s.  These two pieces of code end up being essentially identical after compilation.

Comment: You do not need `zip` to desugar list comprehensions (unless they are of the "parallel" flavor). You do need `concat` though, beyond what you mentioned.

Comment: thanks for your explanation but i still don't know which type signature need to use when coding haskell. do you have any book or website to recommend for me to understand type classes and type signature.

Comment: @user3222659 Learn You a Haskell is how I really got started with the language, followed by Real World Haskell (both are available online for free, or you can pay for them).  After that, it's really just practice.  To be honest, a big part of programming in Haskell is just figuring out the types.  GHCi is great for that, since you can examine the types of expressions with `:type` and `:info` (`:t` and `:i` work too).